# Return to original text using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have some jQuery that when a value is entered will change from `Price Range` to whatever that value is. When that value is removed by the user, I need it to default back to `Price Range`. I have tried an `else if` statement, but my JS/jQuery is not good at all and that is not working. Not sure where to go from here.

jQuery:

```
function modPrice() {
  if ($("#listing-price-selector") && $("#listing-price-selector").next()) {
    var mn = $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#listing_search_form_min_price").val();
    var mx = $("#listing-price-selector").next().find("#listing_search_form_max_price").val();
    if (mn || mx) {
      mn = (mn == "") ? 0 : mn;
      mx = (mx == "") ? 0 : mx;
      $("#priceBox").val(mn + " to " + mx);
      if (parseFloat($("#listing_search_form_max_price").val()) > 0) {
        $("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn + " to $" + mx);
      } else {
        $("#listing-price-selector").text(" $" + mn);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
  <a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-price-selector" role="button" data-toggle="popover">Price Range <span class="caret"></span></a>
</div>

<div id="listing-price-content" style="display: none;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
          <%= f.text_field :min_price, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Min Rent", data: { "binding-name" => "min-price" } %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
            <%= f.text_field :max_price, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Max Rent", data: { "binding-name" => "max-price" } %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note, `jQuery()` returns an object; `if ($("#listing-price-selector") && $("#listing-price-selector").next())` could return `true` even if the elements do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably need to change it dynamically is a listener. Here are steps on how to do it with some documentation.

1. Add `change` listener on the min/max input fields that will change the `listing-price-selector` on the page when the values are edited.https://api.jquery.com/change/
2. Add a html data-attribute to the `listing-price-selector` with the default price. When the values of the input fields are missing, show the default pricing by selecting the changing the text to the data value. https://api.jquery.com/data/